# When using knife ssh commands, it uses a different ruby version on the client than if I ssh into it manually

Tags: ruby, ssh, chef-infra, knife

I am running into this error if I try to use `knife ssh`:

`knife ssh my-node-name.com 'sudo chef-client'`
...
`STDERR: ERROR:  Error installing newrelic_resque_agent: redis requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.`

But if I ssh into the machine as myuser, then `sudo chef-client` works. I found out that this is because the ruby binaries are different:

`knife ssh my-node-name.com 'whoami && sudo which ruby && ruby --version && echo $PATH'`

```
myuser
/usr/bin/ruby
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Now if I ssh into my-node-name.com as myuser and run `whoami && sudo which ruby && ruby --version && echo $PATH`

```
myuser
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.5/bin/ruby
ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-linux]
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

I'm using `chef-client --version` => `Chef: 12.12.15`

How can I make `knife ssh` work?

Comment: This works, but I want to avoid it: ``bundle exec knife ssh my-node-name.com 'PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin" sudo chef-client'``

Comment: using `bundle exec` is the right way to do it.

Comment: It's not the `bundle exec` part that makes it work. It's using the PATH env var. I ended up editing my recipe to use that path when it detects it's on the one chef_environment where this happens, but that seems just as hacky as passing PATH into the chef-client command.

Comment: regular login to the your system and ssh login to your system has different environment variables. if you aligned it, then you are good :)